# How to move the mouse in Windows Scripting VBScript (cscript)

Tags: vbscript, automation, mouse

In the Windows scripting API is there any way to move the mouse through similar to the wshell.SendKey() function?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "No"

The long answer is, if you really know what you're doing you can make calls to the underlying Win32 API to do this for you.

However I wouldn't like to have to do this through PInvoke in .net, or directly from C++.
Considering you can't call out to the Win32 API directly from VBScript, the long answer is also "No".

Sorry